# I want to remove all the 20 values from a python list, how to remove that all 20 values. List = [10,20,30,25,20,40,20,15]

Tags: python

I want to remove all the 20 values element from python list, List = [10,20,30,25,20,40,20,15].
is there any inbuilt method to remove multiple values or what can i do please suggest.

I try to use remove and pop method but they only passed one argument.

Comment: If you want to a new list with same elements but 20s, just do `[i for i in original_list if i != 20]`.  If you want to mutate list, ```for i, e in enumerate(original_list):;if e == 20:;del original_list[i]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list = [10, 20, 30, 25, 20, 40, 20, 15]
value_to_remove = 20

my_list = [x for x in my_list if x != value_to_remove]
```

The value to remove can be of any type.

Comment: thank you ! what you did here is list comprehension?